# Regular expression string search in Java

Tags: java, regex

I know this can be done in many ways but im curious as to what the regex would be to pick out all strings not containing a particular substring, say GDA from
strings like GADSA, GDSARTCC, , THGDAERY.

Comment: it's not clear what you're asking. Is THGDAERY a match? Do you mean a substring, or do you want all strings with G,D,A in that order?

Comment: I want the regex for allstrings not contAining a particular substring. no I wouldnt want that to be a match. as it contains GDA. I want all strings not containing GDA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do negative lookaround

```
"^((?!GAD).)*$"
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regex. Just use `string.contains("GDA")` to see if a string contains a particular substring. It will return `false` if it doesn't.

Comment: I know you don't NEED a regex but I wanted to know how it would be done

Answer (score 1):

If your input is one long string then you have to decide how you define a substring. If it's separated by spaces then:

```
String[] split = mylongstr.split(" ");
for (String s : split) {
  if (!s.contains("GDA")) {
    // do whatever
  }
}
```

Comment: I know you can do it this way but I wanted a regex that did everything. I'm printing if the matcher find the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
String regex = ".*GDA.*";

List<String> testStrings = populateStrings();

for (String s : testStrings)
{
    if (!s.matches(regex))
        System.out.println("String " + s + " does not match " + regex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(?!\\w*GDA\\w*)\\b\\w+\\b");
java.util.regex.Matcher m = p.matcher("GADSA, GDSARTCC, , THGDAERY");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found: " + m.group());
}
```

Comment: **1.** The OP didn't say the strings would contain only word characters; I'd keep it simple and change that first `\w*` to `.*`.  **2.** Once it sees a `GDA` sequence, the lookahead's job is done; that second `\w*` can and should be removed.  **3.** `\b` is a zero-width assertion; it makes no sense to add a quantifier to it.  Some regex flavors treat that as a syntax error, and I wish Java did, too. **4.** Why are you using `\b` anyway?  The OP is trying to match the whole string; you should be using `^` and `$` instead. **5.** Again, your `\w+` should be `.+` unless the OP says otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, I've tried to follow through and make the changes but I keep breaking it. Even simply changing the first `\\w*` to `.*` as you recommended doesn't seem to work. Would really like to learn why.

Comment: I think this is the regex you were trying for: `^(?!.*GDA).*$`.  Also, you should be looping through a list of strings and applying the regex to each one like @mmorrisson did, not searching for multiple matches in *one* string.